# Apache Derby - Does it support 'WITH'

Tags: sql, derby

Couldn't find anything on the Internet for this at all and wondered if someone could help me.

Using Apache Derby with a query in a Spring Boot app:

The query starts like this:

```
WITH dbName AS {
    (Then goes on to select data from tables)
}
```

When running my test cases I get an exception which reads:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "with" at line 1, column 1
```

Does Apache Derby support `WITH`? I can't see any other reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032733/4899193

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research, I can confirm that Derby does not support recursive queries

Found this Issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-11